# How to add whole jdk8 to packaged jar with Maven?

Tags: java, maven, jar, pom.xml

I want to create a standalone javaFX App with jre 8 in jar included. I configured the pom.xml to create a jar with dependencies but i don't know how to add a whole jre as dependency. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you aware of, that the JDK is usually not necessary for running your program? (Also it contains native programs too, not just jars.)

Comment: okay, sorry. say i want to add the jre. rt/jfxrt ...